# C++ Why is global static class not keeping its information in other classes?

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class, sfml

Okay, so I asked a question about [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046423/c-sfml-sprite-not-being-drawn-through-classes) of mine earlier, but no one gave any kind of advice (probably since I couldn't give a more exact area to focus on), so I continued my testing and pinpointed the problem to a much more precise area. (That link will show the majority of my code if there is something missing here for some reason).

So basically, I have a global static class, `static sf::Texture PlayerTexture`, that keeps a texture so that any and all sprites can point to it for their texture. I have a function, `void SetUp()`, that then makes all of the textures load in their information for use. I use this function at the start of `int main()` so that these global static textures will all have their textures ready.  However, when I create a new Object that has a sprite set it's texture to `PlayerTexture`, the texture is not loaded, unless I use the `SetUp()` function inside of the constructor.

Code:

```
//rpg.h
static sf::Texture PlayerTexture;

/*
    NOTE: --Loads in All Textures for use
*/
static void SetUp()
{
    //Load texture.
    if(!PlayerTexture.loadFromFile("C:/Program Files (x86)/Terentia/Files/Textures/player.png"))
    {
        std::cout<<"Error: texture failed to load..."<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

...

```
//main.cpp
typedef std::shared_ptr<rpg::GameObject> ptrGameObject;

int main()
{
    //Should prepare all textures for use...
    rpg::SetUp();

    sf::Sprite tempSprite;

    //Texture is loaded from rpg::SetUp() and works.
    tempSprite.setTexture(rpg::PlayerTexture);

    //Unless rpg::SetUp()  is called in constructor, the texture will be empty.
    //Even though rpg::SetUp() is called before object is created.
    ptrGameObject player = rpg::CreatePlayer();
}
```

So why is `static sf::Texture PlayerTexture` not keeping its texture for use inside of other classes? And how can I set it up so that `PlayerTexture` will have it's texture ready for use anywhere in the code?

(If this code isn't enough to answer my question, the link at the top has much, much more.)

Comment: `static` here means that it is only available within in the translation unit. Every file that includes rpg.h has its own copy of PlayerTexture.

Comment: `static` means many things in different places. When it is at the file level, it means that it is only available in that file/translation unit. Declare it normally in one file: `sf::Texture PlayerTexture` and `extern sf::Texture PlayerTexture` elsewhere.

Comment: @clcto Thanks, it took me a bit to figure it out, but this works perfectly.

Comment: @Joe That would explain a ton.  I guess I am just used to seeing static variables declared in classes.  Thanks.